# Mock in Jest: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I have written tests that trigger the `React` warning

> `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

I know why this warning is there, but I need to test for this case. But I don't want to see the warning when I run my tests.

How can I write a mock that hides that message or even let's me spy on it so I can see it's there?

I am using `React` and `Jest`

Comment: what do you want to test? node key ?  `wrapper.findWhere(node => node.key() === 'foo');`

Comment: No I am writing a webpack loader that will trigger that warning and i don't want to see it in the console of my tests

Answer (score 1):

The warning message gets logged by `console.error` so you can replace `console.error` with a `spy` and check that it was called with the expected warning:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

const List = () => (
  <ul>
    {[1, 2, 3].map((val) => (<li>item {val}</li>))}
  </ul>
);

describe('console.error check', () => {

  let savedError;

  beforeEach(() => {
    savedError = console.error;  // save the real console.error
    console.error = jest.fn();  // replace it with a spy
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    console.error = savedError;  // restore the real console.error
  });

  it('should call console.error with the warning', () => {
    shallow(<List />);
    expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
    expect(console.error.mock.calls[0][0].startsWith('Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.')).toBe(true);  // SUCCESS
  });
})
```

Comment: I already did that, mocking `console.error` did not work unfortunately

Comment: @Lukas What version of `React` and `Jest` are you using?  (This works as expected in my environment)